# Unity sprite sheet performance

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet, texture-atlas

I'm making a microgame game like Wario ware, and all the mini games are prefabs on a single scene.
All of these microgames have their own graphics and I was wondering:
What is better, having all the graphics of all the games on a single sprite sheet or every microgame should haver it's own sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fit it all into a single texture atlas (sprite sheet), then that would be preferable. If you can't have all the graphics of all games loaded into memory at once, you'll have to split the texture atlases, most obviously one per game.